# Google Analytics - Tracking Emails - Event "open" is sent twice with Gmail Client

Tags: email, google-analytics, gmail, tracking

Following the documentation [Google Analytics Email Tracking Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email), I want to track the opening of an Email.

I added the tracking pixel, with all necessary parameters.

`<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&..."/>`

But, **when I open a tracked email with Gmail, the event is fired two times!**

[Tracking pixel loaded twice - Google Chrome > DevTools > Network panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYErY.png)

Note:

- It seems that the next times I open this email (already open before), the event is correctly sent once ;
- If I open the email with my localhost client (I use the fake SMTP [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/)), the event is **always** sent once.

What do you think about it?
The Google Image Proxy (caching images) could be the cause?
(But I guess there would be a notice in the documentation...)

Comment: sometimes it makes 3 image requests also. any fix for this?

Comment: It always makes 3 image calls for loading single image, if the image is large ( larger than single pixel ) loading multiple times makes the image to blink 3 times. However this happens only when the email is opened for the first time. Any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @vikas-kv, unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue. The team did not have this problem last year but now we are receiving multiple events per open / click event